# How to convert the number of X-rays to one of the radiation dose units?

Tags: x-rays, medical-physics

So I have been struggling while trying to wrap my head around how radiation dose from X-rays work. I understand how to calculate how many X-rays would come from an X-ray tube given some settings. I also know that the average energy of these X-rays is 1/3 of the maximum X-ray energy. My confusion was how to use my knowledge of how many X-rays and the average energy of the X-rays to get to numbers of the normally used radiation units.

I know that 1 Roentgen is an exposure which generates 2.58x10-4 C/kg of air and from Roentgens I can convert to all of the other units knowing that the quality factor of X-rays in 1. But I am wondering how many X-rays are required to produce one Roentgen. I imagine that many of the X-rays aren't absorbed by the air so 1 X-ray doesn't equal 1 ionization. I was just wondering if there was a straight forward calculation for this. Also I know that for human tissue there are different factors for different types of tissue. However I was wondering how those factors convert to how many photons at a specific energy are required to get a specific dose.

Comment: "How many X-rays" does not make sense at all. You can't count light rays. Are you trying to ask for the number of photons required to produce a given energy? (That would just be the ratio of the total energy and the photon energy, though)

Comment: Yes I was referring to the number of photons

Comment: I can calculate the number of electrons striking the annode in an X-ray tube. I read [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/hs/dental/sophs/material/rad_phys_II.pdf) that the electrons convert 1% of their energy to x-ray photons. So I thought that the most straightforward way to estimate the radiation dose would be to think about the number of X-ray photons and then think about what percentage of those photons would cause an ionization in air or body tissue. I don't know what the standard way to do this is. I have read about the doses from X-ray machines and I am wondering how they were found.

Comment: Absolute radiometry detecting the absolute energy or particle flux is very hard. Ionization measurements are easier in gases and non-ionic liquids and that's usually what is being used for calorimetry of ionizing radiation. Technologically one usually uses ionization measurements as a proxy for the actual flux.

Comment: A brief survey of definitions confirms that the roentgen (or SI equivalent C/kg) is very poorly defined. A fixed number N of ionizing photons will ionize fewer than N atoms if the optical depth of the to-be-ionized sample is too low, but it could ionize more than N if all photons ionize and some cause multiple ionizations. In either case it's not at all clear what the mass in the divisor is referring to. So in other words, good question.